# mysql sorting characters before digits

Tags: mysql, sorting, alphabetical

I have a table with following values:

```
create temporary table test (name char(6))
insert into test values ('001A1');
insert into test values ('BIKE');
insert into test values ('N01A2');
insert into test values ('NILA');
insert into test values ('NW001');
```

I need to sort them as:

```
BIKE
NILA
NW001
N01A2
001A1
```

I've tried next:

```
SELECT * FROM test
order by IF(name RLIKE '^[a-z]', 1, 2), name
```

And got:

```
BIKE
N01A2
NILA
NW001
001A1
```

How can I make them sorted by letters first and then by digits?

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in collation that supports what you want to do.  That will make it rather hard.  Doing it just for the first letter isn't so hard.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I have one idea that comes close.  This looks for the first digit in the string and sorts by that:

```
order by (case when name regexp '^[^a-zA-Z]' then 0
               when name regexp '^.[^a-zA-Z]' then 1
               when name regexp '^..[^a-zA-Z]' then 2
               when name regexp '^...[^a-zA-Z]' then 3
               when name regexp '^....[^a-zA-Z]' then 4
               when name regexp '^.....[^a-zA-Z]' then 5
               when name regexp '^......[^a-zA-Z]' then 6
               when name regexp '^.......[^a-zA-Z]' then 7
               when name regexp '^........[^a-zA-Z]' then 8
               else 9
           end) desc,
          name
```

This is not *exactly* what you want, because it uses a regular sort after the first digit.  But it might be close enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You comment pushed me in a right direction. I've solved my question.